# variable find_by_attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Could someone please tell me how I can use find_by_attribute with a variable which defines what kind of attribute I am looking for?

For instance,

```
    @answer = User.first.answer
    User.last.find_by_attribute(@answer)
```

The answer attribute has the type string

I hope someone can show me how this could work

**EDIT**

I just realised that this doesn't doesn't get me the results I'm looking for... Here's actually what I need: the name of the attribute I'm trying to access from another user is stored in the answer attribute. So I would need something like User.@answer ... but this doesn't work of course

**EDIT2**

Okay here the solution to my problem:

```
    @answer = User.first.answer
    User.last.send("#{@answer}")
    => true
```

Comment: Are you trying to find a user that has the same answer as the first user?

Comment: This is a strange requirement to have. Are you sure there's no other way to achieve your desired result, e.g. refactoring your models? Maybe you could give some more details on your use case so we can help you with the solution.

Comment: Are you on rails3? And are you trying to get the value of User.last.answer, but in a dynamic fashion where you might not know the name of the .answer attribute?

Comment: @blackbird07: Well my use case actually looks like this: Users answer questions and their answers are stored in the table "user_answers". The answer attribute stores (A, B, C or D) and then there are 4 columns named A, B, C and D which have boolean value and define which answers a user accepts from another user. Now I want to compare the answers of 2 users. So I need to look if the stored answer in the "answer" column is set to true in the related column from the other UserAnswer. I actually wanted to avoid to create seperate tables for the answer and accepted answer

Comment: I hope I explained it right. But I guess breaking this up in seperate tables is the only way

Comment: It's the better option, I think (though I don't understand the interaction where a user accepts an answer from another user). You might still have the option to include another column in your user_answers, e.g. related_answer_id, that you use to relate answers that are associated to one another.

Comment: Okay here the solution to my problem:

        @answer = User.first.answer
        User.last.send("#{@answer}")
        => true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here the solution to my problem:

```
    @answer = User.first.answer
    User.last.send("#{@answer}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which attribute you are querying for in order to use the dynamic finders, e.g.

```
User.find_by_answer(@answer).last
```

Comment: Cannot try this now, but if the attribute you are querying for is not known, you could try something like User.find(:all, :conditions => { attributename => attributevalue })

Comment: what about the find_by_attribute decleration find_by_attributes(match, attributes, *args) ... Wouldn't I be able to achieve something like I wrote above with the right parameters? But your suggestion could work too

Comment: To my knowledge there is no (and cannot be) a "find_by_attribute" method. There is only the dynamic finder method find_by_* where * is your actual attribute. If you type "find_by_attribute", RoR would expect your user to have an attribute called "attribute" and compare it to the value passed.

Comment: that's right, thanks for clearing that up. I just realised that find_by_attribute doesn't give the results I want anyway. I edited my question